# how to measure the realtime FPS in html5 video while playback

Tags: html, video, frame-rate, measure

I'm working on measuring the real-time frame rate of html5 video, does anyone has some ideas? Since I have not find the properties info about frame in html5 video, I have no idea about how to do that.

Another alternative, how to access each frame that html5-video displayed(maybe there are drop frame while playing). I have tried to use canvas to get image from video by drawImage, and get the frame data by getImageData, but it seems that the frame data obtained is not the same as the frame by frame played in video, maybe there are 100 frames played, but we can get 120 0r 70 etc frames by getImageData method.

So in summary, how to get the real time fps or each frame displayed while playing for html5 video?

Answer (score 7):

HTML5 video tag does not support dropped frames or real fps metric yet. However there is a proposal to add such metrics in future. More details at http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_Metrics. The page also has video metrics for other players like flash.

Comment: Thanks, it is good to expose the metric interface, and hope it come out soon.

Comment: SO have I answered your question? If yes, would be great it you accept the answer :-)

Comment: I have used Silverlight MediaElement and can confirm that it provides debugging information such as frame rate, frame drops plus others. Im looking for HTML5 solution that provides such info. From what I read so far, none of the HTML5 solution provides extensive debugging informations. Correct me if im wrong.